# How to change the looks of a gravity form

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I am having troubles in creating a custom look for a gravity form

How to customize a gravity form from wordpress?

It should look like this:
[Gravity Form concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvMy4.png)

Comment: Sj Velasquez, welcome to SO please provide what you've tried,code,a working example so we can reproduce the problem and help you

Comment: sorry I think the last line was confusing. I am confused on how to customize the look and feel of a gravity form. As of now, I just use the default configuration of the form